# How does Wordpress route index.php when a front-page.php is present in the theme?

Tags: wordpress, routes

I just set up a wp theme featuring a front-page.php.

When I point my browser to http://mydomain.com/ the front-page.php is loaded. That's ok.

But... which URL will now trigger the index.php template?

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Matteo

Answer (score 0):

**index.php** is the main file for the theme. It contains the code for the Main Area (below header & above footer) and will specify where the other files will be included.

Your site may be loading **front-page.php** because you may have set static page in your settings to be shown as home page.

Acording to wordpress official doc:

**index.php** 
The main template. If your Theme provides its own templates, index.php must be present.

**front-page.php**
The front page template, it is only used if you use a static front page.

**home.php**
The home page template, which is the front page by default. If you use a static front page this is the template for the page with the latest posts.

---

See this Link for more details on wordpress template hierarchy: [WordPress Codex « Theme Development « Template File List](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List)

Having said that, mention your site URL in question and may be I can help you more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
However front-page.php overrides index.php even if you don't specify the reading settings.

I just want to know if does exists a default routing URL (i.e.: http://mydomain.com/posts/) to get the index.php template.

Comment: I told you standards but what you say that's also possible depending upon your theme's functions.

Comment: well you can define parameters in your theme functions to load different template and then use it like `mydomain.com?template=index.php` or you can give user to select template loading in themes settings page. Kindly VOTE UP and accept answer

Comment: It does not answer the question, I have the same question!

Comment: Same question here. When using `front-page.php`, how can I route `/blog/` to `index.php`?